# how can i make in app buying in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have a child book **mobile application** and my customer asking me that
he wanted to 10 book 5 free and **5 purchasable**.
How can i do that

Comment: i have nothing to find document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a [Native Extension (ANE)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html)

You could make your own, but i would reccomend buying one like this -> [milkmangames.com](http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/tools/#androidiab)

Answer (score 1):

For Android, you need to use an [AIR Native Extension (ANE)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html) (link is a tutorial on how to create and use one). An ANE allows you to run a native code (Java on Android, Objective-C on iOS and Mac, C++ on Windows). You would tie into the native APIs already available for in-app purchases. There are free options available, though they are generally not well documented. I recently had luck with the GCM ANE found [here](http://afterisk.wordpress.com/2012/09/22/the-only-free-and-fully-functional-android-gcm-native-extension-for-adobe-air/) (though you will need to rebuild it in order to use your own icon).

For iOS, Adobe actually provides a way to do it within AIR itself using the `RemoteNotifier` class. I was able to implement this extremely easy. No trouble whatsoever and it is documented fairly well. This also uses native APIs, but it is built into the AIR SDK and is fully supported by Adobe. I highly recommend using this over an ANE. [Read this article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSd6d4f896b3a8801b7be2f55d138e29d5e40-8000.html)